# How is the default item controller registered/invoked in Orchard CMS?

Tags: orchardcms

I'm trying to get my head around how multi-tenancy and routing works in Orchard CMS.

As I understand when Orchard starts a new shell (tenant) all the active modules for that tenant are loaded and any modules that implement `IRouteProvider` "publish" their routes. A `ShellRoute` is then added for each route which will only be matched for requests made to that tenant's hostname/suffix.

The request is then handled in the normal way by MVC (looking in `RouteTable.Routes` for a match).

What I can't figure out is how the default `ItemController` is invoked since I couldn't find a default route for this in the source. Also I notice when browsing to the home page, the `id` route parameter is populated with that of the home page content item so I'm assuming there is some kind of pre-processing going on before the controller is hit?

Comment: Depends if the item has the autoroute part.

Comment: And if it is (for example, the blog content type)?

Comment: If it is, then the slug is first matched, then translated into regular route values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a default `IRouteProvider` - `Orchard.Mvc.Routes.StandardExtensionRouteProvider`. It's responsible for registering default routes to controllers in form  `{module}/{controller}/{action}/{id}`.

And yes, you're right - there is some preprocessing going on. A brief explanation:

- Each item permalink (we call it *an alias*) is mapped to a route
  that points to an action responsible for displaying it. By default -
  `Contents/Item/Display/{id}`. Those mappings are kept in the database (`AliasRecord` and `ActionRecord`).
- There is a special `Route` implementation - `AliasRoute`. This route is then registered once for each module and handles requests that match existing aliases. It all happens in `Orchard.Alias` module.
- If the incoming request matches any alias, the call to `AliasRoute.GetRouteData` returns the underlying mapping. This way ASP.NET MVC framework knows which action to call.